# Azure mobile services

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I've been trying to see the log in console window in azure portal(output) . But i'm not able to see the console output..

Example
I've table tblEmp.

This is my code in tblEmp.read.js

```
function read(id, user, request) {
     console.log("____reading_____");
    request.execute();
}
```

When i execute this , i get the response . But the problem is i dont see console message. Also i've turn on the application logging from Diagnostics logs .

Thanks

Comment: This looks like an Azure Mobile Services question, so I've re-tagged.  Can you please confirm (a) which portal are you using, (b) Is your site an azure mobile app, azure mobile service or a MIGRATED azure mobile service?  The answers are different, generally.

Comment: Hey @AdrianHall , I'm using  migrated azure mobile service .

Comment: Hi @prabinbadyakar, did you mean you have migrated your mobile service to Azure Mobile Apps, and the issue occurred in Azure Mobile Apps?

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT Yes . But for the first 2days we could see that output logs but later we are unable to see them . Can this happen because I changed Application settings? Application Logging is still on .